# Xamarin Forms Get Location

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to execute below code

```
 var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;

 locator.DesiredAccuracy = 100; //100 is new default

 var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);
```

using  Xam.plugin.Geolocator in Xamarin Forms but getting **"This functionality is not implemented in the portable version of this assembly.  You should reference the NuGet package from your main application project in order to reference the platform-specific implementation."** exception.

I am using 3.0.4 version of Xam.plugin.Geolocator from this link https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Geolocator

I have added the nuget package both in Potable porject and droid project. Added

[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation)]
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.AccessCoarseLocation)]

in AssemblyInfo.cs. Also made sure that "Access_Coarse_Location" and "Access_Fine_Locations" is checked in Android Manifest in Visual Studio 2015.

Can any one help what I am missing?

Comment: It looks like you haven't added the geolocator NuGet plugin to your android project?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency injection to access native Android code and get current location.

create a class that will wait for the result

```
class GeolocationWaiter : Java.Lang.Object,ILocationListener
{
    private bool done = false;
    private double latitude = 0;
    private double longitude = 0;


    public Task<GeoLocation> getLocation()
    {
        return Task<GeoLocation>.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!done) { }
            GeoLocation location;
            location.latitude = latitude;
            location.longitude = longitude;
            return location;
        });
    }

    public void OnLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        Toast.MakeText(Forms.Context, "Update", ToastLength.Long).Show();
        latitude = location.Latitude;
        longitude = location.Longitude;
        done = true;
    }

    public void OnProviderDisabled(string provider){}
    public void OnProviderEnabled(string provider){}
    public void OnStatusChanged(string provider, [GeneratedEnum] Availability status, Bundle extras){}
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

call it asynchronously

```
public async Task<GeoLocation?> GetGps()
{
    Toast.MakeText(Forms.Context, "Walk around to get current location", 
    ToastLength.Long).Show();
    var waiter = new GeolocationWaiter();
    locMgr.RequestLocationUpdates(Provider, 2000, 1, waiter);
    ret = await waiter.getLocation();
    locMgr.RemoveUpdates(waiter);
    return ret;
}
```

You can get example on Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.simplesoft.metro

Source code: https://github.com/tripolskypetr/NearestMetro